# Preinstall App on Android x86

Tags: android, user-testing

I'm planning on starting user testing on my app before I release it on the market. The application is targeted to large tablets. I don't have the resources to buy the hardware to give users to test the app so I thought perhaps I could take advantage of Android x86.

There are different ways to [install the app](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/wiki/howtoinstallapps) from the booted live, however i would like to avoid this as almost all of my testers will not be technically affluent to do this comfortably. Thus the best option would seem to be to include the app's apk with Android x86.

I found out how to [get the source code and build it into an image](http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode). However, I can't find any tuts or information on how to include my app's source with the live source.

Does anyone have any ideas? Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The great people at Android x86 helped me solve my question. Here is the best answer I received:

> If you just want to put a prebuilt apk to android-x86 image,
>   that's simple. Just put it to
>   build/target/board/generic_x86/app/
>   (for froyo-x86) or
>   device/common/app/ (for gingerbread-x86).
>
> If you hope to build your app with android-x86,
>   that's another story. Basically speaking,
>   you need to create an Android.mk for your app.
>
> See packages/apps/*/Android.mk as examples.

Thanks, Chih-Wei Huang!

Comment: I did it for androidx86 4.4, but it didn't work, any idea where to place for Kitkat x86? Thanks.